# In Excel, change only the year component of a date

Tags: excel

How do I change just the year component of a date using Excel formulas?

example: 12/31/07 --> 12/31/11

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use (for example)

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1)+5,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a "-1" hidden behind the red 5

Answer (score 2):

A general way to do this:

```
=DATE(2011, MONTH(A1), DAY(A1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have 12/31/07 in cell A1

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1)+4, MONTH(A1), DAY(A1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but just highlighted the date and then went to Find and Select on the Home Ribbon, selected replace and typed in 2010 (the year I wanted to change) and 2013 (the year I wanted to change to) in the Find What/Replace What box and clicked on Replace All and it changed all the dates.

Comment: I think requirement is to change year component of every date

Answer (score 0):

Int(A1)  The time part is the decimal portion

Comment: Doesn't `Int` return the integer part of a number? How will this get the year part of a date?

Answer (score 0):

Please see  the syntax below, you can easily change the year without changing month or date.

Syntax =EDATE(start_date,months)

You can see the article here

Click [here](https://myexceltricks.com/how-to-change-year-without-changing-the-date-and-month/)!